# Модальное окно JS

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать модальное окно, при открытии которого, вылезало окошко со список подключенным к чату пользователей, но возник вопрос, как это сделать, в данный момент у меня это просто
html

```
<div class="online_list">&#9776; Online list</div>
```

css:

```
.online_list {
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 15px;
    justify-content: end;
    border: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Выглядит это так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данный момент это просто текст, я так понял модальное окно можно сделать только через кнопку? Можно ли как то это сделать, чтобы при нажатии на текст открывалось небольшое окно?

Comment: Конечно можно такое сделать

Comment: А не подскажите, как хотя бы сделать, чтобы при нажатии на текст выходило окно, с остальным разберусь

Comment: @Марьяна Вы почти всё правильно сделали, только заголовок вашего вопроса нужно было не на этом сайте прописывать, а в гугле.

Comment: Да я по большей части, чтобы узнать, можно ли сделать модальное окно не через кнопку, в гугле почти везде через кнопки)

Comment: @Марьяна Код открытия модального окна вешается как правило на id или class, а их можно прописать где угодно, в том числе и на блоке с текстом.